# IIS7 Run As User to fix WebSVN permission error

Tags: iis, iis-7, permissions, svn

I'm using WebSVN using direct repository access "file://server/repo".  It's erroring out because IIS 7 isn't running as a user with enough permissions to read the repo.

How can I run IIS7 or the websvn application as a different user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with WebSVN but it sounds like you basically have two options.

1. You can grant access to the user your current worker process is running under to your WebSVN directory.
2. Re-Configure the user that your worker process is running under to a user that has rights to the file. (Application Polls -> r.click Advanced Settings on the correct WP -> Identity)